# UWP App SQLite Access database in Documents Library

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, uwp

***Q: I can't open a SQLite database in my Documents folder:***

App: Universal Windows (10) Platform
Development: C#, Visual Studio 2015
SQLite: Using SQLite.net
Targets: Windows 10 Desktop and Windows 10 Phone

Deployment: From Visual Studio or Sideloaded (Do not need Store deployment)

```
using SQLite;
using SQLite;   
using SQLite.Net;   
using SQLite.Net.Async;   
using SQLite.Net.Attributes
```

### I can:

Open and read from a database included in the project as content:

```
using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection
(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), ".\\mydb.db3"))
{
//Read queries
}
```

Open/Create  and Read/Write a database to the apps workspace:

```
string path = Path.Combine
(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,"another.db3");

using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection
(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path))
{
//CRUD
}
```

- Copy another.db3 to Documents
- From there copy to an External Memory Device (SD Card)

## I can't

- Open the database in Documents or SD

I use a FilePicker to choose the db in Documents or the SD
I then use the File.Path property when attempting to open the database connection

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFile File = await FilePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();  
string path = File.Path;
```

I get the following error message when I attempt to open that connection:

> Exception thrown: 'SQLite.Net.SQLiteException' in SQLite.Net.dll
>   SQLite-GetAllVendors: Could not open database file: C:\Users\me\Documents\another.db3 (CannotOpen)

Have added SQLite .db and .db3 file associations.

```
      <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name=".db">
            <uap:DisplayName>SqliteDB</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:EditFlags OpenIsSafe="true" />
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.db</uap:FileType>
              <uap:FileType>.db3</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap:Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
```

Have added the relevant Capabilities

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
    <uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary" />
    <uap:Capability Name="videosLibrary" />
    <uap:Capability Name="userAccountInformation" />
    <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
  </Capabilities>
```

***Surely there is some way to open a SQLite database in Documents or on a memory stick form a Universal Windows (10) app.***
Thx in advance

Answer (score 13):

Because SQLite opens the database file directly rather than going through the file broker it can only see databases in the app install and application data  (the directories that the app has direct file permissions to read and read/write respectively).

Changing this would require an update to SQLite to use streams from the file broker objects (StorageFile and StorageFolder) to access locations that have permissions granted via capabilities, pickers, etc.

Comment: Thanks Rob,
This is a clear and unequivocal answer in "black and white".
Your SQLite detail also helps a lot.

I implemented a solution, which works, where the db file is copied back to the application folder and opened from there.

Comment: Don't forget to mark Rob's response as the answer if it answered your question.